# Click event on input value

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to alert '#water' when I click the text '#water'. Instead I am getting 'Object Object'. Am I completely missing the boat here? The idea is that if there are multiple values, say "#water", "#tea", "soda", that you can click each text individually rather than just triggering the event by clicking the text area.

```
   <input type='text' id='input-tags' name='hashtags' value="#water">

   <script>
     $('#input-tags').click(function(){
       alert($(this))
     })
   </script>
```

Comment: alert(this.value); no need to use jq on input props that are homogenous since 1998...

Comment: dandavis is right, you can even drop the script tags and do it inline, with onclick="alert(this.value);"

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` is a reference to the object. You're getting the expected behaviour.

If you want to see what the input holds, use `$(this).val();`

Comment: Awesome, thank you all for the quick response! Works great now. I still have a 10 minute limit but will check this once it's over.

Comment: $(this).val() == this.value; why be wasteful?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  $('#input-tags').click(function(){
   alert($(this).val())
 })
</script>
```

Comment: hint: there is no .va() method... i didn't downvote, but typos should be fixed or someone else will...

Comment: oh yes i wrote here not copy paste

Answer (score 0):

jQuerys Sizzle (the engine used for selecting things) does not return the HTMLObject (`<input type='text' ...>`) but a jQuery Object:

```
[input#input-tags, context: input#input-tags, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
0: input#input-tags
context: input#input-tags
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

To shorten things: The correct way of getting `#water` is either

```
$(this).val()
```

(http://api.jquery.com/val/) or

```
$(this)[0].value
```

since $(this)[0] represents the HTMLObject.

Comment: $(this)[0].value == this.value; why be wasteful?

Comment: Just wanted to explain how jQuery Objects are working ;)